# How do I implement a function to count how many songs an artist has in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, text-files, hashset

What I want to do is count how many songs an artist has within a text file of over 100,000 lines of different songs and different artists.
For example: If I have 3 lines in the text file and all of them are by Elvis Presley it should have an output similar to this.

```
Who let the dogs out | Elvis Presley | (1) 
Can't help falling in love | Elvis Presley | (2)
Hound Dog | Elvis Presley | (3)
```

I've got it to do what I want up until that number part where it counts how many songs it's put out. If anyone could help me understand how I could implement this I'd be really appreciative.

Comment: There are two things that you need to do.
First, you have to read your file and retrieve that data (name of the song, artist name..) and then you have to have some kind of counter that actually increments each time. You simply have to retrieve that counter once you have read your whole file.

Comment: You understand how hashmap works right? If an artist is not in the hashset, insert it with value 1 otherwise increment the stored  value by 1.

Answer (score -1):

It is definitely not the best way to do it but it is the easiest to understand :

```
public int countArtist(String artistName, int count) {
count = 0;
try {
  File myObj = new File("yourFile.txt");
  Scanner myReader = new Scanner(myObj);
  while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
    //read/parse your data and retrieve your artist name
    String artist = myReader.nextLine();
    if (artistName.equals(artist)){
      count++;
    }
  }
  myReader.close();
  return count;
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  System.out.println("An error occurred.");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: 1.) you need to read the entire file for every query and 2.) please don't use `==` for testing String equality https://dzone.com/articles/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-jav

Comment: "It is definitely not the best way to do it but it is the easiest to understand" ....

Comment: well, then where is part in which `count` gets set back to `0` for the next iteration? a local variable would do just fine here. as it stands now, it's unfortunately a wrong solution for multiple reasons (plus it won't compile with the comma in line 3)

Comment: That will be my last message for you. He asked for a way to understand how to do it. Not for the whole working code.